# Create a New folder using Java Program on Windows and Linux machines

Tags: java, windows, linux

How can I create a Folder using Java code on both Windows and Linux machines?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
new File("/path/to/folder").mkdir();
```

If you want to created nested folders (i.e. more than one folder on the path may be missing), then use `mkdirs()`. See [`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Note that forward slashes would normally not work on windows, but Java normalizes the path and translates forward to backward slashes.

Comment: It is not working for me . Can any one let me know the reason ? I have posted this already , but still couldn't able to resolve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940987/creating-a-folder-within-web-server-under-public-html-in-java

Comment: reply For above comment - Resolved the issue : Instead of giving path as " /xyz.com/appFolder/ " , should give full path as "home/XYZ/public_html/appFolder"

Answer (score 4):

```
 try{
    String strDirectoy ="test";
    String strManyDirectories="dir1"+File.Separator+"dir2"+File.Separator+"dir3";

    // Create one directory
    boolean success = (new File(strDirectoy)).mkdir();
    if (success) {
      System.out.println("Directory: " + strDirectoy + " created");
    }    


    // Create multiple directories
    success = (new File(strManyDirectories)).mkdirs();
    if (success) {
      System.out.println("Directories: " + strManyDirectories + " created");
    }

    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

- [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Use File.mkdir() (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir())

Answer (score -2):

```
try{    
     int a,b;
      a=mk.dir();
      b=newfile("\n new.java());
    }
```

Comment: Please add some details, at least `catch` block.