# how to create folders for a specific user on a web application container?

Tags: java, web-applications

I want to create a folder on my server corresponding to every user in my web application.

How i can create a new folder through java dynamically?
And i want that new folder to contain resources corresponding to a particular user.Can i now access those resources as a client by directly providing the URL of that resource
For ex..

```
    http://localhost:8080/myapp/newfolder/a.pdf
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't expose the folder directly through URLs as that would be a serious security concern where one user can access the folder of another user if the naming scheme is understood.

Instead, I would

- create folders by user name in a separate location that is not accessible through the URL, using the [`java.io.File.mkdir()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29).
- write a simple Servlet that would read the [`servletRequest.getPathInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29), identifies the user name from the path, along with the file to be served. For this to happen, the servlet class and URL pattern should be defined as follows:

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>read-file</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/read-file/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

  To access a file `a.pdf` of user `xyz`, the URL would be `http://server/read-file/xyz/a.pdf`.
- check if the user accessing the URL is same as the user name found in the path info.
- read the file through a `FileInputStream` in blocks of, say 1MB, and write into the `ServletOutputStream` (without storing anywhere in between) after setting the appropriate values in the [`Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses) headers.

Comment: Yeah but many websites on the internet expose the url of the pdf files on them..Will that be a totally wrong approach?

Comment: Can i do it this way.I can use the servlet to identify a user and then forward his request to the url of the resource??

Comment: simply forwarding , wont make your resource secure. you need to filter out non authorized access.

Comment: The URLs on those websites can still read as "/abc/xyz.pdf", but they don't point directly to the physical files on the server. They run through a simple servlet that does some housekeeping work, like number of accesses, lite authentication/authorization check if applicable, etc.,

Comment: if a request is  for /abc/xyz.pdf..how can a servlet intercept it??

Comment: Please see the update of how the servlet mapping and url pattern should be.

Answer (score 0):

Just check this.
[Create a New folder using Java Program on Windows and Linux machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427270/create-a-new-folder-using-java-program-on-windows-and-linux-machines)

further you can store the mapping of path of the directory and corresponding user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directory in Java using `new File("path"+File.seperator+"foldername").mkdir()`

I assume you are aiming to create it within your war folder in web app. This is not a recommended approach, because you will loose user data if you redeploy your war.

Better approach is have a repository path configured into your application using a System property

For eg: repository=D:\userdata
And create your folders within this repo.Then you may need a custom servlet to allow download of this files, you will have to read the file and put it in servlet response. This folder wont be affected by redeployment of war file.

Even this approach is wrong as you cannot scale to multiple appservers in this approach, It is always better to store user data in a central repository(amazon s3, rackspace files), or in  a database.

Comment: Can i store complete files in mongodb?