# Creating a folder within web server under /public_html/ in Java

Tags: java, webserver, jersey

I am trying to create a folder within web server using Java File handling APIs in my RESTFul web service developed using JERSEY.
According to my understanding, when I target "xyz.com" , it by default points out /home/xyz/public_html/ in my server.

So when I try to create a folder as follows

```
        String appFolderPath = "/xyz.com/appFolder/";
    File userNameFolder = new File(appFolderPath + userName);
    if (!userNameFolder.exists()) {
        folderPath = userNameFolder.mkdir();
    }
```

The above code fails, I am not getting any exception, and no folder is created.
How exactly I suppose to do it ? How to give path for public_html/ folder ?

Another point is, is it not happening because of permission issue ? , I actually tried another way , I manually created /appFolder under public_html/ and give full read write permission to that folder, but still I couldn't create any folder within that using above code.

Please let me know how to achieve it ? Any Sample code ?
Also if possible let me know if JERSEY does give me APIs to make it simple ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To point to public web directory use

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
String path = context.getRealPath("/");
```

and append your path to the `path` (above resolved)

Comment: Since I am using jersey and developing web service, to get servlet context we have to add a parameter as follows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831042/restful-how-to-get-access-to-httpsession-inside-the-service-class

Answer (score 0):

> According to my understanding, when I target "xyz.com" , it by default points out /home/xyz/public_html/ in my server.

What makes you think so? You're operating files in the code snippet given, so your path means `/xyz.com/appFolder/` and nothing more. And it's very likely you're facing a permission issue trying to create folders like this.

As for absense of exception, that's a design feature of Java file API not to throw exceptions on certain failures, but rather return erroneous error codes. Check what is returned by `mkdir()` call and you'll find `false` there, as a signal of failure.

Comment: At least is it correct to refer a folder as "/xyz.com/appFolder/" ?

Comment: yes it is returning false for mkdir(). What might be the possible cause ? is it a permission issue? if that is the case to what folder I have to give read write access?  definitely I can not give it for public_html folder.

Comment: First try to use 'mkdirs()' instead of 'mkdir()'. If it won't help, then you're facing a persimmion issue. To find out the folder to grant permission on, execute userNameFolder.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: I used both way, using mkdirs() and using getAbsolutePath() , getAbsolutePath() returning "xyz.com/appFolder" which is expected. But still it is mkdirs() returning false.

Comment: I am not even getting securityException .

Comment: Resolved the issue : Instead of giving path as " /xyz.com/appFolder/ " , should give full path as "home/XYZ/public_html/appFolder"